Solve Orr–Sommerfeld equation equation and plot a vector plot
I am trying to solve Orr–Sommerfeld equation and trying to plot a vector plot. Can Initial condition be given as a vector v(y,t=0)=[1 2 3]?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orr%E2%80%93Sommerfeld_equation
At different time instant how can I plot vector from Orr-Sommerfeld equation?

Why not to read this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181479/analytic-solution-to-orr-sommerfeld-squire-equations-for-a-special-case/181506#181506 ?

Thank you. Its a great help.
